# Memory leak while displaying Panoramic image

Tags: objective-c, ios, panoramas

I am using PanoramaGL v0.1 to display Panoramic image.
My Panaromic image is having resolution 4000 * 2000,size:1 mb.
While displaying the image app is taking around 60mb of size as checked on instruments in simulator. Also whenever i tap on button to display Panoramic image memory is getting allocated, but never gets released.

Following is code:

```
NSObject<PLIPanorama> *panorama;

panorama = [PLSphericalPanorama panorama];
[(PLSphericalPanorama *)panorama setTexture:[PLTexture textureWithImage:[PLImage imageWithCGImage:imgPanoramic.CGImage]]];
[plView setPanorama:panorama];

panorama = nil;


- (void)dealloc 
{ 
  [plView release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Need some guidance where i'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use ARC? I guess you don't because you are releasein plView in dealloc. I guess you will have to release panorama before you assign nil. Or autorlease it.

Comment: No Hermann, i'm not using ARC... also panorama is static class in which PLSphericalPanorama is getting allocated which is autorelease object...

Comment: Ah, I did not know that it was static. Therefore I deleted my answer which is misleading in this case.

Comment: You should share a bit more information or code. Does instruments provide more information? Is this really leaking? Meaning are there always about 60M added when another panorama is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the textures after loading panoramic image.

```
[plView removeAllTextures];
```